# json_decode of array not rendering correctly in HTML output

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a database with some data encoded in json format. I would like to output an HTML table but I ran into a snag when the particular piece of data in the json encoded data cell was an array.  The word "Array" is output for the field in the HTML table along with "Notice: Array to string conversion in...".

My code uses a MySQL statement to retrieve data and the usual fetch array operators.  The specific code used to render the json encoded data is:

```
$user_params = json_decode($row['params'], true);
```

and to create the output:

```
<td>{$user_params['phone']}</td>
<td>{$user_params['ride_catagory']}</td>
```

The first line above renders correctly since the data is encoded as a single text string, however, the second line gives me the "Array" and message since it is encoded as an array within the json data.  How can I fix this?

Here is the contents of the 'params' database field:

```
{"phone":"444-336-5678","birth_year":"1965","volunteer":[""],"ride_catagory":["10-12","13-15","16 plus"],"ride_note":"on","membership_visible":"on"}
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($user_params)` output ?

Comment: So most likely that $user_params['ride_catagory'] is not a single value, but an array and you'll have to add another level to access it's specific part. $user_params['ride_catagory']['something']...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could manage the thing in different ways.
You actual way is relying on knowing already the keys of the `array` you get, so I guess you can also assume that you know the type of content in it.
If you know the type you can just **perform a particular behaviour when you know that the content of the element will be an `array`** as well **.**

```
<?php
$row = array(
    'params' => '{"phone":"444-336-5678","birth_year":"1965","volunteer":[""],"ride_catagory":["10-12","13-15","16 plus"],"ride_note":"on","membership_visible":"on"}'
);
$user_params = json_decode($row['params'], true);
?>
```

and then something like (in a quite blindly way):

```
<td><?= $user_params['phone']; ?></td>
<td><?= implode($user_params['ride_catagory'],', '); ?></td>
```

or like (conceptually better):

```
<td><?= $user_params['phone']; ?></td>
<td>
    <?php
        if(is_array($user_params['ride_catagory'])) {
            echo '<table><tr>'.PHP_EOL;
            foreach ($user_params['ride_catagory'] as $category) {
                echo sprintf('<td>%s</td>'.PHP_EOL, $category);
            }
            echo '</tr></table>';
        } else {
            echo $user_params['ride_catagory'];
        }
    ?>
</td>
```

It all depends on you *how flexible* you want the code to be (like working even if you don't know what type of data an array element will contain).

#### NOTE

I would add that **you shouldn't directly print value to the output if you didn't validate them** (otherwise you expose yourself to *XSS attacks*)**.**

Comment: I am getting a syntax error when I use either code perhaps because my HTML column tags appear as part of the elements in a larger variable = statement, i.e. $arr = <table border=1 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=2>...<td>{$user_params['ride_catagory']}</td></table>; I tried assigning the implode statement to a variable $cat and then use <td>{$cat}</td> which works, however, I get a warning "implode(): Invalid arguments passed in...".

Comment: @user3520372 you should check all the `<?php`/`?>` opening and closing tags and be sure all the HTML is in HTML place and that PHP is enclosed into the above tags. I also fixed the code. Regarding the **"implode(): Invalid arguments passed in..."** warning you should check and be sure that value passed as parameter to `implode()` is of type _array_; otherwise the function will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to join the values

```
<td>{$user_params['phone']}</td>
<td>{implode($user_params['ride_catagory'],',')}</td>
```